# How can I make sure that there is enough time for my MediaRecorder to prepare in Android?

Tags: android, video, android-camera, android-mediarecorder

I am trying to get the media recorder to work. The problem is that my code crashes when I prepare my Media recorder. Like so: `mMediaRecorder.prepare()`

What happens is, that it throws an IOException.

On this discussion https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5050 I read that the problem is that the there needs to be sufficient time before and after you call `mMediaRecorder.prepare()` (look at 6th post in that discussion).

Can anyone here help me out? How can I make sure that my Media recorder has enough time to prepare?

Comment: Can you show the exception, especially the top parts from the framework code?  Bug 5050 was filed roughly 4 years ago and involved a native crash, so it's not clear that it's related to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Use an onPreparedListener to ensure it's ready](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener.html)

EXAMPLE:

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener(){

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.start();
        }

});
```

---

EDIT: I got this code from a tutorial in grokkingandroid.com.

MediaRecorder recorder = null;

```
private void startRecording(File file) {
   if (recorder != null) {
      recorder.release();
   }
   recorder = new MediaRecorder();
   recorder.setAudioSource(AudioSource.MIC);
   recorder.setOutputFormat(OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
   recorder.setAudioEncoder(AudioEncoder.AMR_WB);
   recorder.setOutputFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
   try {
      recorder.prepare();
      recorder.start();
   } catch (IOException e) {
      Log.e("giftlist", "io problems while preparing [" +
            file.getAbsolutePath() + "]: " + e.getMessage());
   }
}
```

This is just an example but as you can see, the `prepare()` and `start()` methods are in the `try-catch` block, so if it DOES start while the `MediaRecorder` hasnt been fully prepared, the `IOException` will be caught. I think this is the only way to handle this situation.

Comment: That's for `MediaPlayer`.  Is there an equivalent for `MediaRecorder`?

Comment: @fadden  Whoops, I misread your question, sorry. Please see my edit